# how do you write PostgreSQL query for getting group of sum of records that have the same value

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have the following table

```
id | items   |  price  |
  1| item_1  |  15.0   |
  2| item_2  |  10.0   |
  3| item_1  |  15.0   |
  4| item_1  |  15.0   |
  5| item_2  |  10.0   |
  6| item_2  |  10.0   |
  7| item_3  |  25.0   |
```

and I want the following output

```
 items   |  price  | count | sum  |
 item_1  |  15.0   | 3     | 45.0 |
 item_2  |  10.0   | 3     | 30.9 |
 item_3  |  25.0   | 1     | 25.0 |
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to do query like this

```
select items, price, count(items) as count, sum (price) as sum from table1 group by items, price
```

Comment: This query will not generate the output expected by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

We can use analytic functions here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(price) OVER (PARTITION BY items, price) sum,
              COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY items, price) count
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT DISTINCT items, price, count, sum
FROM cte
ORDER BY items;
```